# What is the advantage of wearing polyester for basketball?

Tags: basketball

Basketball uniforms are usually made out of polyester. What advantage does polyester have over, say, cotton for playing basketball? I personally did not feel any different whether wearing polyester or cotton.

[image]

Comment: My initial guess is athletic departments are low on funds, and these are cheap and last a long time. That's just a guess though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for using polyester is,

- Provide support and ventilation.
- Absorbs water and transfers body perspiration away from the skin.
- Prevent sweat buildup.
- Although this material dries quickly, the sweat is expelled onto the
  outer layers of the garment and wind may cause the player to feel
  cold.
- It is best to wear in hot or humid conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Also, polyester / polyester blends are more lightweight than cotton, especially when cotton gets heavier as it gets soaked with sweat. This also helps with runners as well.

Nike has Dri-FIT. Adidas has ClimaCool.